# PCI passthrough without VT-d

Tags: xen, virtualization

My CPU is [Intel T9300](http://ark.intel.com/products/33917/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T9300-%286M-Cache-2_50-GHz-800-MHz-FSB%29), it supports VT-x, but it does not support VT-d. I am using Xen pvops virtualization. I have a PCI device, and my host system can work without it. So I am thinking if it is possible to pass it to my guest vm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 3.0, Xen has provided PCI passthrough to a paravirtual (PV) guest without VT-d CPU/Motherboard extensions. A PV guest means that the guest is running a special Xen kernel that is aware of the hypervisor. Xen PV guest kernels exist for Linux, NetBSD, FreeBSD, OpenSolaris and Novell Netware operating systems.

Xen cannot provide PCI passthrough to a HVM (fully virtualized) guest without VT-d. An example of an HVM guest would be Windows.

This [wiki entry](https://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Xen_PCI_Passthrough) discusses Xen PCI passthrough.

Comment: It is technically possible actually. Years ago there was the ["NativeDom" patch](http://xen.1045712.n5.nabble.com/Intel-VT-d-Neocleus-1-1-mreged-code-for-PCI-passthrough-td2532085.html) (based on the [original](http://www-archive.xenproject.org/files/xensummit_4/Neocleus_HVM_PCI_Pass-through_Zana.pdf) passthrough [work](https://lists.xenproject.org/archives/html/xen-devel/2007-05/msg01144.html) by Neocleus) that allowed the thing to work on HVM even in the IOMMU-less scenario, albeit with a couple of limitations. Not sure what it has been of it.